# If conditon 1, wait until condtion 2 is true. - bash shell -

Tags: android, bash, shell, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a script that sets values based of the return of `grep -c`, I then use those values to determine the state of a connected device, and from those values put the device in a certain state. I want the script to check whether the device successfully entered the state I want it in. Its for android devices, so I've been able to get away with `fastboot wait-for-device` and `adb wait-for-device` so far.

Now I'm trying to get it to recognize a recovery mode state, I have accomplished this with `RECC=$(adb devices | sed -n '2p' | grep -c 'recovery')`. Unfortunately  there is no command that stalls the script until recovery is connected. I've been playing around with `until`, but haven't been successful.

```
#!/bin/bash

ADBC=$(adb devices | sed -n '2p' | grep -c 'device')
FBTC=$(fastboot devices | grep -c 'fastboot')
RECC=$(adb devices | sed -n '2p' | grep -c 'recovery')

    if [ $RECC = 1 ]
    then

echo "******* [SUCCESS] ******"
echo "*                      *"
echo "*  recovery connected  *"
echo "*                      *"
echo "************************"

  sleep 2

    elif [ $ADBC = 1 ]
    then

echo "******************************************"
echo "*                                        *"
echo "*  Not in recovery, booting to recovery  *"
echo "*                                        *"
echo "******************************************"

      adb reboot recovery &> /dev/null

    until [ $RECC = 1 ]
    do

  sleep 1

    done

  clear

echo "******* [SUCCESS] ******"
echo "*                      *"
echo "*  recovery connected  *"
echo "*                      *"
echo "************************"

  sleep 2

    elif [ $FBTC = 1 ]
    then

echo "*********************************************"
echo "*                                           *"
echo "*  In fastboot mode, rebooting to recovery  *"
echo "*                                           *"
echo "*********************************************"

      fastboot reboot recovery &> /dev/null

        until [ $RECC = 1 ]
        do

      sleep 1

        done

  clear

echo "******* [SUCCESS] ******"
echo "*                      *"
echo "*  recovery connected  *"
echo "*                      *"
echo "************************"

  sleep 2

    elif [ $FBTC = 0 ] && [ $ADBC = 0 ] && [ $RECC = 0 ]
    then

echo "********* [ERROR] *********"
echo "*                         *"
echo "*  Cannot detect device!  *"
echo "*                         *"
echo "***************************"
echo
echo
echo "====== [Press enter] ======"

read

    fi
```

The script works as far as booting the recovery when adb or fastboot is connected, throwing an error when there is no connection, and detecting when it is connected. It hangs on the `until` command tho. My understanding is that the `until` command waits until the value is true, then continues the script. Quite to the contrary, my experience so far has told me that `until` just locks itself in a loop if value is false.

FYI, if your wondering what it is I'm greping:

The return of `adb devices`, with a device in recovery mode:

```
List of devices attached 
0599b116        recovery
```

The return of `fastboot devices`, with a device in fastboot mode:

```
0599b116        fastboot
```

The return of `adb devices` on a booted device with adb enabled:

```
List of devices attached 
0599b116        device
```

Comment: In your `until` loop how is the value of `$RREC` going to change? What changes it? Your loop is just `sleep 1 and test again`.

Comment: When it boots into recovery the value of $RECC should change to  1, the `fastboot reboot recovery` or `adb reboot recovery` puts the device into recovery mode. I'm hoping to catch the $RECC change from 0 to 1, and then print a `success` when the value changes.

Comment: When do you fetch the value and store it into `$RECC` again? Your script (running on your host machine, no?) is stuck in your `until/sleep` loop and isn't doing any other work.

Comment: `RECC=$(adb devices | sed -n '2p' | grep -c 'recovery')` 
Should change from 0 to 1 when it is in recovery mode. I'm trying to catch that change, and `echo success ` when the value changes (once the device is booted to recovery).

Comment: @Etan Reisner I'd also like to point out that i know 
 
`RECC=$(adb devices | sed -n '2p' | grep -c 'recovery')` changes because it prints `success` when I'm in  recovery

Comment: You should do something like `until [ $RECC = 1 ];  do sleep 1; RCC=$(adb devices | sed ....); done`

Comment: Yes, but you aren't calling that to see if it changed once you hit the loop. You just keep testing the *original* value you assigned to the variable. See @RobinHsu's edit for the sort of change I was referring to (minus the `RCC` typo).

Comment: Bash variables don't magically, dynamically update by calling the original command again each time you get their value. They are static once set. If you had a `RECC` *function* which called that `adb` command then your loop could work (almost) as written though.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate yalls time, `until [ $RECC = 1 ]; do sleep 1; RECC=$(adb devices | sed -n '2p | grep -c 'recovery'); done ` works, and I put `$RECC`, `$FBTC`, and `$ADBC` in a function since i use them multiple times in the script this code is going into, and I can just call it within the until loops.